# Is the sum of these two sets open or closed?

Tags: analysis

$C_1$ = {$(x, y) | x > 0, y > 0, xy \ge 1$} - closed convex set

$C_2$ = {$(x, y) | x = 0$} - closed convex set

Where the Minkowski sum of two sets is A + B = { a + b | $a \epsilon A$, $b \epsilon B$}

Then, $C_1 + C_2$ = {$(x, y) | x \ne 0, y > 0, xy \ge 1$}

Not really sure if the sum of the two sets is correct but then it would be closed, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C_2$ is the $y$-axis, and $C_1+C_2$ is the right half-plane (excluding the $y$-axis), it happens to be open in this example, but not closed.

To elaborate, take any $(x,y)$ with $x>0$ i.e. any point in the right half-plane. 
Then $(x,\frac1x)\in C_1$ and $(0,y-\frac1x)\in C_2$, so $(x,y)=(x,\frac1x)+(0,y-\frac1x)\in C_1+C_2$, which proves that the right half-plane is contained in $C_1+C_2$. For the other direction take any $(x,y_1)\in C_1$ (so by assumption $x>0$ and $y_1=\frac1x$) and any $(0,y_2)\in C_2$, then $(x,y_1)+(0,y_2)=(x,y_1+y_2)$ clearly belongs to the right half-plane since $x>0$.

Comment: Thanks Mirko. Just checking but my $C_1 + C_2$ set is correct?

Comment: @user32 $C_1+C_2$ is the right half-plane which is $\{(x,y):x>0\}$, which is not what you had in your question. What you had was the _epigraph_ of $C_1$ (i.e. all points on and above $C_1$)

Comment: Ahhh ok I understand now. Thanks a lot.