# some statements on sum of two subsets of plane. open, closed etc .

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$W=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x>0,y>0\}$

$X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x\in\mathbb{R},y=0\}$

$Y=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: xy=1\}$

$Z=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: |x|\le 1,|y|\le 1\}$

1. $W+X$ is open

True as sum of an open set and a closed set is always open.(W open, X closed)

2. $X+Y$ is closed

False, Sum of two closed set need not  be a closed set. But I am not able to figure out in this case what will be the summed up set.

3. $Y+Z$ is closed

True as sum a closed and a compact(Z) is closed.

Thanks for helping and correcting me

Comment: How do you define the sum, is this _union_ or is it [_Minkowski sum_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) ?

Comment: $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$

Comment: see my related answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035460/is-the-sum-of-these-two-sets-open-or-closed I will think of what you are asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [Is the sum of these two sets open or closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035460/is-the-sum-of-these-two-sets-open-or-closed)

But I will give answers here anyway (more questions here).

1. Correct, and a bit more is true: The sum of an open set and *any* set is open.
2. The sum is the plane, except the $x$-axis $\{(x,y):y\not=0\}$. Indeed if $(x_1,0)\in X$ and $(x_2,y_2)\in Y$ then clearly $y_2=\frac1{x_2}\not=0$, so 
   $(x_1,0)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_2)$ cannot be on the $x$-axis.
   Conversely, 
   if $(x,y)$ with $y\not=0$ then $(x,y)=(x-\frac1y+\frac1y,y)= (x-\frac1y,0) + (\frac1y,y)\in X+Y$.
   Alternatively think of the effect of adding $(x,0)$ to any set, this is a translation of the set along the horizontal axis by the vector $\langle x,0 \rangle$. So, $Y$ is the hyperbola, the graph of $xy=1$ (one branch in the I-st Quadrant, and one branch in the III-rd Quadrant). We translate $Y$ to the left and to the right, all possible ways, sweeping the upper and the lower half planes, except the points on the $x$-axis (since $Y$ has no points on the $x$-axis). Of course, removing the $x$-axis leaves an open (but not closed) set.
3. It is correct.